# How to add css code inside custom vue directive file?

Tags: typescript, vue.js

I want to have an image fallback directive that simply fills the parent `div` with a gradient background if the image somehow failed to load.

I've tried this directive file:

```js
export default {
    bind(el: any, binding: any) {
        try {
            .....
            img.onerror = () => {
                el.parentNode.classList.add("fallback");
            };
        } catch (e) {

        }
    },
};
```

with this template:

```html
<div><img v-image-fallback :src="xxx" /></div>
```

and style:

```
.fallback {
    width: 600px;
    height: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    background: radial-gradient(...);
}
```

How do I combine the directive and css part? Or is that even possible?

Answer (score 0):

The parent node is not guaranteed to exist until the [`inserted` hook](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html#Hook-Functions) in Vue 2 or the [`mounted` hook](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/custom-directive.html#hook-functions) in Vue 3.

Switch from the `bind` hook to one of the above:

```js
// MyDirective.js
export default {
  // BEFORE:
  bind(el) {
    console.log(el.parentNode) // => null ❌ 
  }

  // AFTER (Vue 2):
  inserted(el) {
    console.log(el.parentNode) // => <div> ✅
  }

  // AFTER (Vue 3):
  mounted(el) {
    console.log(el.parentNode) // => <div> ✅
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/modify-parents-class-from-directive-jbz5j?file=/src/ImgFallbackDirective.js)